# Can I use the `e` notation on MyEtherWallet?

Tags: myetherwallet, bignumber

I just found out about the existence of the "minification" process.

You probably know about it already, but if you don't, it basically means that 
`1000 = 10^3 = 1E3` .

So `1000` *minified* is `1E3`.

Or `10'000'000` is `1E7`.

And `0.000'000'000'000'000'01` = `1E-17`

My understanding is that by using this notation not only you get to reduce big numbers by a few bits (i.e. `100'000'000` = `1E8` ), but you also get to stop having to count zeros all the time, thus reducing *human-related mistakes* (of which I usually make many).

Questions are:

1. Can I specify `1E6` gas units or `2*1E6 gas` units in MyEtherWallet ?
2. Can I specify `1E-17 ETH` in MyEtherWallet?

Answer (score 2):

instead of asking others first you could have tried yourself. Anyway, I have tried it out for you and the answer is:

1. Yes
2. Yes

Here is the test:

### As you write out the numbers on MyEtherWallet the text-box stroke kindly becomes green thus hinting that the operation will be successful.

[image]

### As you generate the transaction, you can clearly read the number **1E-17** which is nicely understood by your anthropoidal brain, as opposed to the *machinese* 0.000000000000000000000001 *(I didn't count the zeros)*.

[image]

As I don't have yet 10 reputation points I am unable to show the third link where the transaction took place, but you can check it did by checking out this address on etherscan.io (ropsten network).

0x955f0e3c64564035e950ed5029069336fd27e9c1

Hope this was helpful!